# Flask form submission without Page Reload

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have a simple flask app that displays a table of data. One of the columns has a form.
[image]

I tried to follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flask-form-submission-without-page-reload/) tutorial on how to submit the form without it refreshing the page each time.

While I got it to work, it only seems to grab the data from the first row, regardless which row's form I submit.

This was working fine without the no-refresh attempt. Concretely, if I submitted the form that resides in the second row, it would pick up the second rows data point.

Any ideas? Am I supposed to apply some sort of indexing to the javascript function?

```
<table id="customer_df">
        <thead class="text-primary">

          <tr>
            {% for col in column_names %}

            {% if loop.index == 13 %} 
            <th style="display:none;"></th>

            {% else %}
            <th class="text-center">
            
              {{col}}
             
            </th>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in row_data %}
          <tr>
            {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}

            {% if loop.index == 1 %} 
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('client_details_page', customer_name=row_) }}" target="_blank"> {{row_}}</a></td>

            {% elif loop.index == 12 %} 



            <td>
                  
              <form method="POST" id="reassign-form">
                <input type="hidden" name="mhh_key" id ='mhh_key_id' value="{{ row[12] }}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="mhh_name" id='mhh_name_id' value="{{ row[0] }}"></input>
                <input type="hidden" name="curr_initial" id='curr_initial_id' value="{{ row[11] }}"></input>
                <input type="text" name="reassigned_initial" id="reassigned_init" value="{{ row_ }}" size="3" maxlength="140"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="reassignment_dt" value="{{ reassignment_request_date }}"></input>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Reassign"/>
                </form>


            </td>
            {% elif loop.index == 13 %} 

            <td style="display:none;">

            {% else %}

            <td>{{row_}}</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

         
        </tbody>
  
      </table>

<!--- Prevent page refresh after form submitted-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('submit','#reassign-form',function(e)
                 {
    //console.log('hello');
    console.log($("#mhh_name_id").val())
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/',
      data:{
         mhh_key:$("#mhh_key_id").val()
        ,mhh_name:$("#mhh_name_id").val()
        ,curr_initial:$("#curr_initial_id").val()
        ,reassigned_initial:$("#reassigned_init").val()
        //value_in_app.py:id_in_form.val()
      },
      success:function()
      {
        alert('Reassignment Submitted.');
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop you're not changing the input `id`. So when you are taking the `id` from the JavaScript, it always takes the first value (i.e first row). And it is a bad idea to use same `id` everywhere. Your `id` should be unique.

One thought is to add `row_number` to each `id`. and pass this `row_no` to your javascript function.

First create the `row_no` variable right after the first loop.

```
<tbody>
{% for row in row_data %}
{% set row_no = loop.index %}
  <tr>
    {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}
```

Then add it to all your `id`

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return new_fun(event, {{ row_no }})">
  <input type="hidden" name="mhh_key" id ='mhh_key_id_{{ row_no }}' value="{{ row[12] }}"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="mhh_name" id='mhh_name_id_{{ row_no }}' value="{{ row[0] }}"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="curr_initial" id='curr_initial_id_{{ row_no }}' value="{{ row[11] }}"></input>
  <input type="text" name="reassigned_initial" id="reassigned_init_{{ row_no }}" value="{{ row_ }}" size="3" maxlength="140"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="reassignment_dt" value="{{ reassignment_request_date }}"></input>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Reassign"/>
</form>
```

Also I changed the JS function little bit so that it will take this number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function new_fun(e, num){
    # console.log(num)
    # console.log($("#mhh_name_id_"+num).val())
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/',
      data:{
         mhh_key:$("#mhh_key_id_"+num).val()
        ,mhh_name:$("#mhh_name_id_"+num).val()
        ,curr_initial:$("#curr_initial_id_"+num).val()
        ,reassigned_initial:$("#reassigned_init_"+num).val()
        //value_in_app.py:id_in_form.val()
      },
      success:function()
      {
        alert('Reassignment Submitted.');
      }
    })
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you that worked. Just one change needed, when creating the row_no I had to change it to {% set row_no = loop.index %}, you had it reversed, index.loop.  Other than that works like a charm!

Comment: yup. sorry for that. i will change now.